# Error messages clogging Telethon resulting : Server sent a very new message xxxxx was ignored

Tags: python, telethon

Whenever launching telethon from an existing session I receive two error messages:

Server sent a very new message with ID xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, ignoring Server sent a very new message with ID xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, ignoring

And thereafter it gets clogged , preventing any execution.

The answer I got from another post is "in Windows time settings, enable automatic setting of time and time zone". But I am using a Linux system, and the system is set to the Asia/Shanghai time zone. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the reason. The time difference between the local environment and the Telegram server is too large. After manually adjusting the time to correct the delay, the problem was fixed.